# Skipping list of lists elements

Tags: list, prolog

I have this nested list:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
        [2, 7, 2, 1], 
        [3, 3, 7, 5], 
        [4, 4, 1, 7]]
```

And I'm trying to skip the first list of this nested list, and the first element of each list. I want it to become like this:

```
list = [[7, 2, 1], 
        [3, 7, 5], 
        [4, 1, 7]]
```

So far I have this:

```
% skip first list in list of lists
skip_first_list([_|Tail], Tail).

% attemping to skip first element in each of the lists
skip_first_list([[_ | HeadTail] | Tail], X) :-
    skip_first_list(Tail, R),
    append(R, [HeadTail], X).
```

Which does not produce the correct result:

```
?- skip_first_list([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 7, 2, 1], [3, 3, 7, 5], [4, 4, 1, 7]], X).
X = [[2, 7, 2, 1], [3, 3, 7, 5], [4, 4, 1, 7]] ;
X = [[3, 3, 7, 5], [4, 4, 1, 7], [2, 3, 4]] ;
X = [[4, 4, 1, 7], [7, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4]] ;
X = [[3, 7, 5], [7, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4]] ;
false.
```

Whereas I'm after this answer:

```
X = [[7, 2, 1], [3, 7, 5], [4, 1, 7]]
```

My result so far seems to be showing I'm appending in a reverse/incorrect order, How can I fix this? I don't really understand what order Prolog evaluates expressions. Any any would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the specification is that you provide a list of lists and that:

- the first sublist is ignored (not part of the output); and
- that for the remaining sublists, all heads are ignored as well.

So we better split this into two predicates:

- `remove_heads/2`, which removes the heads of all sublists; and
- `remove_upper_left/2` which remove the first sublist, and then uses the above predicate to pop the heads of the sublists.

We can perform `remove_heads/2` for instance with recursion:

```
remove_heads([],[]).
remove_heads([[_|H]|T],[H|T2]) :-
    remove_heads(T,T2).
```

finally our `remove_upper_left/2` simply ignores the head of the list, and makes a call to `remove_heads` with the tail:

```
remove_upper_left([_|T],T2) :-
    remove_heads(T,T2).
```

Or in full:

```
remove_heads([],[]).
remove_heads([[_|H]|T],[H|T2]) :-
    remove_heads(T,T2).

remove_upper_left([_|T],T2) :-
    remove_heads(T,T2).
```

This then produces:

```
?- remove_upper_left([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 7, 2, 1], [3, 3, 7, 5], [4, 4, 1, 7]],X).
X = [[7, 2, 1], [3, 7, 5], [4, 1, 7]].
```

and works in the opposite direction as well:

```
?- remove_upper_left(X, [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 7, 2, 1], [3, 3, 7, 5], [4, 4, 1, 7]]).
X = [_G1364, [_G1370, 1, 2, 3, 4], [_G1376, 2, 7, 2, 1], [_G1382, 3, 3, 7, 5], [_G1388, 4, 4, 1|...]].
```

So here it prepends a variable to every list, and prepends a variable (possibly a sublist) to the output.

Furthermore we have here two predicates at the price of one: we can also use `remove_heads/2` in the future if we want to pop the heads of all the sublists in a list of lists.